# What is the Cisco 7200 VXR Netflow Default Sample Rate?

Tags: cisco, netflow

I am trying to collect netflow data from a Cisco 7200 VXR router. I need to specify the sample rate, but I cannot seem to get the information from the cisco router and I do not know what the default sample rate is.

Do you know what the default netflow sample rate of a cisco 7200 VXR is?

Thanks in adance.

Comment: Do they have a standard sampling rate? Or do they collect netflow on every packet?

Comment: Netflow is not sampling protocol by default, unlike sflow.